# What are the advantages of handling oracle packages/stored procedures with liquibase?

Tags: oracle, liquibase

What are the advantages of handling oracle packages/stored procedures with liquibase when packages can be compiled everytime?
Is the main advantage the fact you can compile only those that have changed?

Answer (score 1):

This is primarily an opinion based question and answer. Everything below here is just my opinion.

The main benefit is that you are using a single technique to manage your database 'schema' changes (where schema means the structure and programmability of your database). As long as you are using some sort of automation to manage your database, you should use that automation as much as possible, in as many areas as possible. If you have to manage your database with liquibase + perl scripts + shell scripts + sqlplus scripts, then you are making it harder than it should be.

Making the system work reliably and without manual intervention should be the first goal, making that performant is close secondary goal. Of course, if the first part results in some unacceptable downtime, then the solution might need to be revisited.